# Configure VS Code code runner extension to display CPP warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, warnings, vscode-code-runner

I am wondering how I could configure the Code Runner extension on VS Code (MacOS 10.15) to display warnings (i.e. `-Wall`?)

Would there be a simple, almost permanent method so code runner will always display warnings no matter which CPP file I build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! This is possible.

Go to the **Workspace Settings**, search for `code runner` and click on `Executor Map`:

[image: Workspace Settings for Executor Map]

You may then use the following JSON code:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
       // ...
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -Wall -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }    // used -Wall here
}
```

Save it and quit from the file and jump to the code you want to run. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to select the run type. Select `C` simply and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I changed ```"c"``` to ```"cpp"``` and ```gcc``` to ```g++```

Comment: @IraH. yes, it's dependent on which stuff you want to compile/interpret with.